# Add a new Entry to ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

What i am trying to do here is to have a button to add a new entry to my  custom listView,something like add to card concept.

However, everything working fine, it is just that when i click the button only one entry is added, and when i click it for the second time nothing changed.

My Fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_port_group, container,false);
    injectViews();
    mGroupPortAdapter=new GroupPortLazyAdapter(getActivity());
    addToList.setOnClickListener(new OnAddToListClickLinsten());
    return rootView;
 }


public class OnAddToListClickLinsten implements OnClickListener{

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mGroupPortAdapter.add(new GroupPortInModel("23424",12321324,"0177889062"));
    portGroupListView.setAdapter(mGroupPortAdapter);

}

 }
```

This is the lazy Adapter

public class GroupPortLazyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private int[] colors = new int[] { 0x30bebebe, 0x30FFFFFF };

```
public GroupPortLazyAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, -1);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
     ViewHolder holder;


    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.port_group_custom_list_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.acountId = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.port_account_id);
        holder.serialNo = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.port_serial_no);
        holder.phoneNumber = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.port_phone_number);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.acountId.setText(getItem(position).getAcountId());
    holder.serialNo
            .setText(String.valueOf(getItem(position).getSerialNo()));
    holder.phoneNumber.setText(getItem(position).getPhone());
    int colorPos = position % colors.length;
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView acountId;
    TextView serialNo;
    TextView phoneNumber;
    int position;
}
```

}

Comment: you code filling the view with the `holder` is obviously wrong. the `holder` variable should be declared inside `getView()` and initialized even, if `convertView != null`.

Comment: I have edited my code, yet still no chance,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `mGroupPortAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` instead of `portGroupListView.setAdapter(mGroupPortAdapter)`?

Also, your try using this as your `getView()`.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    GroupPortInModel item = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.port_group_custom_list_view, null);
    }

    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.port_account_id))
        .setText(item.getAcountId());
    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.port_serial_no))
        .setText(item.getSerialNo());
    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.port_phone_number))
        .setText(item.getPhone());

    int colorPos = position % colors.length;
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Try using the getView I just editted into the answer.

Comment: Thanks lot my friend both of what you have pointed out were correct,yet i just found out what was the error, My listView was nested in scrollView, which cause the problem. thanks for your answers ..

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it working. If my answer helped, please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).